# Python - parse csv data - algorithm error

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, csv, pandas

I need to parse a big csv file (1Gb), which contains weather data.
The file itself is here:
ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/2014.csv.gz

Additional info (stations code and file format):
ftp:// ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt
ftp:// ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/readme.txt

I need to find there information on Kiev and Dnipropetrovsk and visualise monthly averages.
I have written an algorithm for finding data and it's averages, but it doesn't give me a data on the latest month.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = open('2014.csv', 'rb')
try:
reader = csv.reader(f)

avgK = 0
avgD = 0
date = 0
mon = 1
avergK = []
avergD = []
count_date = 1

for row in reader:
    if row[2] == 'TAVG':
        count_date +=1
        date = (int(row[1]) % 10000)

        if row[0] == 'UPM00033345':    
            avgK += float(row[3])/10.0

        elif row[0] == 'UPM00034504':
            avgD += float(row[3])/10.0

    if (date//100 > mon):
        print date //100, mon, date%100, avgK, avgD
        avergK.append(avgK/count_date)
        avergD.append(avgD/count_date)
        mon += 1
        avgK = 0
        avgD = 0
        count_date = 1
        continue
finally:
    f.close()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(avergK)
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Average Temperature')
plt.title('AVG in Kiev 2014')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(avergD)
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Average Temperature')
plt.title('AVG in DNIPROPETROVSK 2014')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Is it possible to solve it using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use pandas here, but you do not need them to solve current problem. What happens is that you store a monthly average only when you find a line with a new month. But when you reach end of file, you should alse process last month.

Your loop should be:

```
for row in reader:
    if row[2] == 'TAVG':
        count_date +=1
        date = (int(row[1]) % 10000)

        if row[0] == 'UPM00033345':    
            avgK += float(row[3])/10.0

        elif row[0] == 'UPM00034504':
            avgD += float(row[3])/10.0

    if (date//100 > mon):
        print date //100, mon, date%100, avgK, avgD
        avergK.append(avgK/count_date)
        avergD.append(avgD/count_date)
        mon += 1
        avgK = 0
        avgD = 0
        count_date = 1
        continue

# store values for last month
avergK.append(avgK/count_date)
avergD.append(avgD/count_date)
```